# Edit(Reshape) GeoJSON data coming from database added on leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, geojson, geometry, leaflet-draw

I have multiple buildings data displaying on map as GeoJSON, but we have to change their shapes while they are on map and update latest shape GeoJSON in database. How can I make GeoJSON editable on map and change geometry?

This fiddle has a polygon, all I want is just to change shape of this polygon https://jsfiddle.net/f81nxbec/30

```
var osmUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
          osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
          osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {
            maxZoom: 28,
            attribution: osmAttrib
          });
        var map_rgb = L.map('map').setView([71.47487550973892,
              30.194821775512267], 14).addLayer(osm);

    const bldgs={
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              71.47487550973892,
              30.194821775512267
            ],
            [
              71.4749063551426,
              30.194605015383754
            ],
            [
              71.4752148091793,
              30.19471745251533
            ],
            [
              71.47508069872856,
              30.194905233830244
            ],
            [
              71.47487550973892,
              30.194821775512267
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

 var building_layer = L.geoJson(bldgs, {color: "#FF0000", weight: 3, fill: false});
 var drawnItems = new L.featureGroup();
building_layer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
console.log("here")
  drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
});

map_rgb.addLayer(drawnItems)

 function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on('click', function (e) {
        alert(e.target.feature);
        //or
        alert(e.target.feature);
    });
}
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
            draw: {
                polygon: {
                    shapeOptions: {
                        color: 'red',
            fill: false,
                    },
                    allowIntersection: false,
                    drawError: {
                        color: 'orange',
                        timeout: 1000
                    },
                    showArea: true,
                    metric: false,
                    repeatMode: true,
                },
          edit: {
                featureGroup: drawnItems
            }
        }})
        map_rgb.addControl(drawControl);

        map_rgb.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (e) {
            var type = e.layerType,
                layer = e.layer;
            drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
        });
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f81nxbec/30/

This fiddle has a polygon, all i want is just to change shape of this polygon

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Links fail over time, and are unlikely to be followed (just as a matter of best security practice). Coding Questions  without code are likely to be closed. Please add the code inside the Question body., not a a comment or link.

Comment: @TomazicM please check now

Answer (score 2):

Reason why you can't see your polygon is wrong order of coordinates in `.setView`. Leaflet uses `[lat, lng]` coordinate order in it's methods and functions. For GeoJSON, coordinate order `[lng, lat]` is OK, since this is GeoJSON standard.

So relevant part of the code should be (setting also higher zoom to at least see polygon):

```
var map_rgb = L.map('map').setView([30.194821775512267, 71.47487550973892,], 19).addLayer(osm);
```

Reason why you can't edit existing polygons is in missing `}` after `draw` option definition and one too many at the end. It should be like this (correct indentation greatly helps avoiding such errors):

```
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
  draw: {
    polygon: {
      shapeOptions: {
        color: 'red',
        fill: false,
      },
      allowIntersection: false,
      drawError: {
        color: 'orange',
        timeout: 1000
      },
      showArea: true,
      metric: false,
      repeatMode: true,
    }
  },
  edit: {
    featureGroup: drawnItems
  }
});
```